# React data table with support for router linking

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and I can't find a datatable which supports router linking on cell click.  I am currently using MDBDataTable and it seems it doesn't support it. Can you please give me some pointers? Thanks!

Comment: You want a user to be re-directed to a different URL when he clicks a table cell ? Are you using React-router?

Comment: Thanks @Friednoodles! Yes. I want to redirect to a different route within my react application.

Comment: sorry I forgot to ask. are you also using history? @user911

Comment: Not sure what you meant but I guess no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table ?

Sounds like it supports `Link`: https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/issues/89